# Making my SVN Public

Tags: ssh, svn

I'm looking todo an SVN checkout on a server so I need to make my local SVN public.

I looked into GITHUB, but I'm not willing to pay or let the world see my project. Are there any alternates?

Okay so I went through this tutorial: http://www.petri.co.il/setup-ssh-server-vista.htm

Had some issues, so I did this: mail-archive.com/cygwin@cygwin.com/msg84875.html

Now I'm wondering how let the SSH access my SVN repo found in c:/wamp/svnRepo.

Any tutorials or advice (please no: go read this book crap) greatly welcome!

Comment: wait, you want a public viewable repository, but you're not willing to let the world see the project ? Do you mean public available, but private ?

Comment: What Sirex said. I don't understand what you are trying to do, either.

Comment: Basically I only want me to be able to access it via the server I want todo a check out on.

So basically not public, but certainly viewable with the right user/pass.

im guessing my ip would server as a connection to my computer from the server

Answer (score 0):

Given comments on original question;

Why not just use svn over ssh ? - That's what i use (hence maybe biased).

such as: svn co svn+ssh://your.remote-server.com/home/svn/test

Comment: SVN is installed on my local computer. I'm trying to make it a server with open SSH so I can do an SVN co on the remote server.

Comment: ok. install ssh server on the local machine, and then (from the remote machine) run the co command. should work.

Comment: Thats my question really, do i find out my ip and then connect to that via ssh?

Comment: yea, use your pubic ip. It should work as long as you have the ability to ssh in from outside. I normally run my ssh on non port 22, which takes a little more fiddling, but you can still use svn over ssh on it.

Answer (score 0):

https://bitbucket.org/ offers private repositories on free accounts, but have limitations on how many users can access that repository before you need to pay.

Google Code offers project hosting, using either Mercurial or SVN, and you can configure your project to be private. However, this will require that your users use their Google Account to access the repository, which may not be desireable.